# Unable to eval a string array

Tags: php, eval

How can i change this to a JSON Array? im using the eval technique but this is not working. Im getting this kind of response from our upx server:

```
array(
    'invoice' => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'realid' => '4',
        'address_rev' => NULL,
        'relation_data_id' => '3',
        'contact_set_rev' => '3',
        'business_data_rev' => '4',
        'private_data_rev' => NULL,
        // etc..
    )
); 

var_dump($newdata); // String
eval("\$newdata = \"$newdata\";");
var_dump($newdata); // Still stays as a string as shown above....
```

Any clue?

Ty Already!

Comment: What on earth outputs that? If you want to transmit a literal PHP array, [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You'll facepalm really bad when I tell you this..

But the reason it's still a string is because you wrapped it in `""` inside your call to `eval`, and of course wrapping letters inside of quotes will make it.. (*drum roll* ..) a string.

```
 eval ('$newdata = ' . $newdata . ';'); // this will do what you want
```

---

If you want to turn it into json right away, use the below:

```
 eval ('$newdata = json_encode (' . $newdata . ');');
```

- [PHP: json_encode - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Omg, slap me :(, how can i not see that :O probally because im working for like 13 hours straight now! however, ty for the answers!

Comment: For people who arrived here from Google: another possible source of error when doing this is neglecting to add the semicolon to the end of the eval'ed string. Creating a temporary variable which you pass to eval (at least during development) allows you to double check the string for syntactical correctness.

Answer (score 2):

```
var_dump($newdata); // String
eval("\$newdata = $newdata;");
var_dump($newdata); // Still stays as a string as shown above....
// eval("\$newdata = \"$newdata\";");
//                    ^         ^
```

Remove the double quotes. Your just putting it back into a string...

Although as I said above, if you want to transmit a PHP array, you should be using [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `json_encode` of php. you can try

```
$json_array = json_encode($your_array);
```

This will give you json encoded array. Then you can do json_decode on $json_array to get original contents back

Check if your php has JSON extension